# Google Colab: how to turn off suggestion window?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, tooltip, google-colaboratory

In **Jupyter** notebooks you are able to press Shift + Tab whenever you need a suggestion window

In **Google Colab** it seem to just appear itself all the time, see example:
[image: suggestion window pops up as typing]

Is there a way to turn it off *OR* have it as some keybind similar to Jupyter to see it only when needed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can disable automatic completions in the editor settings.

[image]

Comment: Interesting that this actually works, given that the problem is **not** the code completion suggestion box, but rather the documentation info box.  They should rename that checkbox in the settings to something like "show code completions and documentation while typing", then I would have found it right away.

Comment: This doesn't make the info box stop displaying.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. It only disabled the autocomplete feature; the documentation popups are still being triggered.